# How to merge data of two tables with different column name in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I get final output based on table 1 and table 2 in Big Query

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

**Final Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`.  If the columns are in the same order:

```
select *
from table1
union all
select *
from table2;
```

In general, though, it is better to list out the column names instead of using `*`.  Note that in the result set, the names from the first `select` are used for the result set.

Comment: How the values of column "revenue" and "final_revenue" can sit under one column i.e. revenue

Comment: @AwanishDubey . . . That is how `union all` works.